# NuGet API get license text

Tags: c#, nuget

I have the name and the version of a nuget package and need to extract the license text of each package.

I managed to read out the license url by reading several blogs, but the documentation overall is really sparse. Since the license url is deprecated I have to read out the license information itself. But with the approach that I took that does not seem to be possible:

```cs
public static async Task<IPackageSearchMetadata> GetNugetPackageMetaData(string name, string version)
       {

           //workaround for beta/alpha
           if (version.Contains("-"))
           {
               int dashIndex = version.IndexOf("-");
               version = version.Substring(0, dashIndex);
           }

           int[] versions = Array.ConvertAll(version.Split("."), int.Parse);

           NuGetVersion nuGetVersion = new NuGetVersion(versions[0], versions[1], versions[2]);

           PackageIdentity packageIdentity = new PackageIdentity(name, nuGetVersion);

           List<Lazy<INuGetResourceProvider>> providers = new List<Lazy<INuGetResourceProvider>>();
           providers.AddRange(Repository.Provider.GetCoreV3());  // Add v3 API support
           PackageSource packageSource = new PackageSource("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");
           SourceRepository sourceRepository = new SourceRepository(packageSource, providers);
           PackageMetadataResource packageMetadataResource = await sourceRepository.GetResourceAsync<PackageMetadataResource>();
           IPackageSearchMetadata searchMetadata = 
               await packageMetadataResource.GetMetadataAsync(packageIdentity, new SourceCacheContext(), NullLogger.Instance, CancellationToken.None);

           return searchMetadata;
       }
```

Is there a another possibiltiy to get the license text with nugetv3 or even better, the whole nuspec file?

Comment: If by NuGet API you mean the nuget.* packages on nuget.org, given that nuget only [started supporting embedded licenses and license expressions from 4.9.2](https://github.com/NuGet/Announcements/issues/32), you'll need to upgrade to at least the 4.9.2 packages. The v3 packages were from VS2015, so quite old now.

Comment: or if you're just reading the nupkg as a zip file and read the nuspec, yes, it's listed in there: https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/reference/nuspec#license

Comment: AFAIK, the NuGet API just gives you the nuspec properties. It won't download/extract/lookup the license text from the URI/file path/license expression for you.

Comment: I see. What I need in this case is the element embedded in<license> inside the nuspec. I saw this request on the nuget documentation https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/12.0.2/newtonsoft.json.nuspec. Would it be fine to just query this endpoint programatically or is there a better way?

Comment: It's up to the package author to provide that metadata. I think nuget.org still accepts packages using licenseUrl, but even when they don't, old packages will never be updated. But packages might have an embedded license file, rather than an expression, so you'll need to support all these scenarios for your program to be robust. Also, if you're not already, you might want to consider using the [NuGet API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview) and the registration pages, as it provides more info, such as a url to download the license file when the package embeds one.

Comment: Thank you @zivkan. Hadn't really considered these cases yet.